# Problem while expanding equations.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to study analysis of algorithms yet I found my algebra skills are very poor. So now I began restudying algebra (factoring, destributive property, simplifying, expanding) so I can handle mathematical equations better. But no matter what I do, I can't seem to explain how the following equation work.

$\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{6} = \frac{N^3}{6} - \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{N}{3}$

I think

$\frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{6}$

has been expanded into

$\frac{N^3}{6} - \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{N}{3}$

I have a feeling I am thinking something stupid, but I really don't understand the right side of the equation.

- Can anyone explain how the formula got expanded?
- What part of algebra should I study to understand equations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as $$\frac{n\left[(n-1)(n-2)\right]}{6}.$$ Try to [FOIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method) the right side of the numerator and then split the fraction. Use that $$\frac{a+b+\cdots}{\gamma}=\frac{a}{\gamma} + \frac{b}{\gamma}+\cdots.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. However I don't understand the equation that much. I am using a screen reading software because I am blind. This software only reads texts for me, but not notations or symbols. Right now, my screen reader reads your fomula as "n[(n(unknown symbol)1)(n(unknown symbol)2)]6" and "a+b+(unknown symbol)(unknown symbol)=a(unknown symbol)+b(unknown symbol)+(unknown  symbol)". Do you mind making it textual? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user235991 Oh sorry about that. What I meant was that (a+b+c)/d = a/d + b/d + c/d. Are you aware of FOIL, or any other method for distribution?

Comment: @user235991 n(n-1)(n-2)/6 = n(n^2 -2n -n +2)/6 = n(n^2 -3n + 2)/6 = (n^3 -3n^2 +2n)/6 = n^3/6 - 3n^2/6 + 2n/6 = n^3/6 - n^2/2 + n/3.

Comment: this is very helpful! I finally understand it! Thanks very much!

Comment: do you mind looking at the other equation? I forgot to include it before. Figured asking how to simplify and expand equations in one question could be fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @user235991 Make a new question and ping me in the comments.

Comment: [done](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274998/simplifying-equations)