# simplifying equations

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have been trying to study analysis of algorithms with mathematical induction yet I found my algebra skills are very poor. So now I began restuddiing algebra (factoring, destributive property, simplifying, expanding) so I can handle mathematical equations better. But no matter what I do, I can't seem to explain how the following equation work.

$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$

I think
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)
$$
have been simplified to

$$
\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$

I have a feeling I am thinking something stupid, but I really don't understand how the right side of the equation have been simplified.

- Can anyone explain how the formula got simplified?
- What part of algebra should I study to understand equations like this?

Comment: @MathMajor
 here you go :)

Comment: $\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} +(n+1) = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} +\frac{2(n+1)}{2} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ You should study factoring and expanding polynomials.

Comment: @user222031 Hey are the explanations here okay? Let me know.

Comment: @MathMajor yes, the explanations are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both expressions have the common factor $(n+1)$, which we can factor out.  Hence we write $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=(n+1)\left[\frac{n}{2}+1\right]=(n+1)\left[\frac{n}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\right]=(n+1)\frac{n+2}{2}=\\=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Unfortunately, I am blind and I am using a screen reading software to read texts for me, but not notation and symbols. Right now my screen reader reads your formula as "n(n+1)2+(n+1)=(n+1)[n2+1]=(n+1)[n2+22]=(n+1)n+22==(n+1)(n+2)2". Do you mind making the formula more textual? Like adding ^ before the exponent? Thanks.

Comment: Here the idea is that the fraction with nominator n times (n+1) and denominator 2 can be written as x times (n+1). If one adds (n+1) by distributive law the result is (x+1) times (n+1). Now x was n divided by 2. adding 1 to it is the same as adding the fraction 2 divided by 2, this gives (n+2) divided by 2 for (x+1), so (x+1) times (n+1) is (n+2) times (n+1) divided by 2

Comment: @mvw thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

user222031 got the easy one. If one knows that
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \sum_{k=1}^n k
$$
(the sum of the first n integers is n * (n+1) / 2).
Then it is also obvious, because another term ($n+1$) has been added to the sum, now summing the first n+1 integers, which means that n needs to be changed to n+1 in the result formula, giving (n+1)*(n+2)/2.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Unfortunately, I am blind and I am using a screen reading software to read texts for me, but not notation and symbols. Right now my screen reader reads your formula as "n(n+1)2=(unknown symbol)k=1nk". Do you mind making the formula more textual? Thanks.

Comment: This formula helps to find the sum of the first 100 integers very quickly. It can be proven by induction or geometrical by doubling the colums of height k into a rectangle of size n times n+1. Jacob Bernoulli came up with summation formulas for the first n integers to the power of 2,3,4 etc. There is also a relation to integration, e.g. The formula for the sum of the  integers each squared is a polynomial of order n to the power of 3.

Comment: While the formulas are rendered into symbols by the MathJax software, its source is a pure textual representation, commands in the latex typesetting language. If you could point your reader to the source code view of the web page, you might locate it within the html. However i have no idea if this is practical for you.

Comment: I'll try, but I am not sure if it will be helpful. Do you mind translating the equation of the other answer into a readable way n(n+1)2+(n+1)=(n+1)[n2+1]=(n+1)[n2+22]=(n+1)n+22==(n+1)(n+2)2 ?